# My date stamp in the database is not changing. Python / MariaDB

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mariadb

My first project, so there is a heavy noob alert here :) I am building a weather station on my Raspberry Pi. Python.

I am trying to store my weather observations in a database. Everything is uploaded fine, but the date is not changing. I think there might be something wrong with my loop?

```
import time
import bme280_sensor
import ds18b20_therm
import database

interval = 5

temp_probe = ds18b20_therm.DS18B20()

db = database.weather_database()

while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time <= interval:
        ground_temp = temp_probe.read_temp()
        humidity, pressure, ambient_temp = bme280_sensor.read_all()
        print(humidity, pressure, ambient_temp, ground_temp)
        db.insert(ambient_temp, ground_temp, pressure, humidity)
```

This is a snippet from my database.py

```
def insert(self, ambient_temperature, ground_temperature, air_pressure, humidity, created = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")):
    params = ( ambient_temperature,
        ground_temperature,
        air_pressure,
        humidity,
        created )
    print(self.insert_template % params)
    self.db.execute(self.insert_template, params)
```

Comment: What does the database schema look like?

Comment: There might be something wrong with the interval variable and condition. Could you explain what you want to achieve here? You want to create a database entry every 5 seconds?

Comment: No sleep between measurements?

Comment: I think we need to see the `db.insert` method's code.  And perhaps also the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <your-table>;` in the db console.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to have an interval of 5 sec between the entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition of `insert`

```
def insert(self, ambient_temperature, ground_temperature, air_pressure, humidity, created = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")):
```

the default value of `created` is only evaluated once, when the interpreter first reads the function definition.  A better approach would be to set a default of `None`, and override it in the function body.

```
def insert(self, ambient_temperature, ground_temperature, air_pressure, humidity, created=None):
    if created is  None:
        created = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: ok, this definitely is an improvement. Thanks. Now it creates a different time stamp per entry. But it uploads an entry every 1 second and apparently ignores my "interval" - even if I change internal to 100 there is no change.

Comment: Every time the condition on the inner `while` is `False`, start time gets reset in the next iteration of the outer loop.  It would be simpler to use `time.sleep(interval)` to do this I think.  Also easier on your CPU :)

Comment: Or simply let MySQL insert `NOW()`?

Answer (score 0):

What about putting this in the last line?

```
db.insert(ambient_temp, ground_temp, pressure, humidity, time.time())
```

Because I can't see a point where you inserted timestamps to the database